# why does this if statement not resize its respected image?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, if-statement

I have an if statement that checks to see if an image displayed in the DOM was originally smaller than 600px wide, and if it was, the image is resized to a different width. However it's not working, I've been debugging for a while now and still can't figure this out. Any ideas as to why?

jQuery

```
$('span.i_contact').each(function() {    

var imgWidth = $(this).data('imageWidth');    
console.log(imgWidth)
if (imgWidth < 600) {
    var newWidth = ((imgWidth / 600) * 300);
    console.log(this);  
    $(this).css({
        "width":newWidth
    });    
} 


    var pos_width = ($(this).data('posWidth')) / 2.025;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('posHeight')) / 2.025;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('posX')) / 2.025;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('posY')) / 2.025;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid orange",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    });

var n = $(this).data('index');
$('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode);

});

$("span.o_contact").each(function() {    

var imgWidth = $(this).data('imageWidth');
if (imgWidth < 600) {
    var newWidth = ((imgWidth / 600) * 300);
    console.log(newWidth);   
    $(this).css({
        "width":newWidth
    });    
}    


    var pos_width = ($(this).data('posWidth')) / 2.025;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('posHeight')) / 2.025;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('posX')) / 2.025;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('posY')) / 2.025;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid green",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });

var n = $(this).data('index');
$('.o_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode);       
});
```

ERB (how the images are generated)

```
<% n = steps.index(step) %>
<h2 style="margin-left:20px;"> Step <%= n + 1%></h2>
<div class="stepcontainer">
<div class="steptext">
    <%= step.instruction %>
</div>
<div class="modalbutton">
    <%= render(step.flags.new) %>   
</div>


<% if step.input_contact.present? %>
    <div class="productimg">
    <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.i_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-image-width="<%= step.i_connection.image.dimensions.first %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>   
        <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">   
            <%= link_to image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:medium), class: "iconnection" ), "#{step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
            <div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>    
        </div>      
    </div>

    <% if step.i_connection.cord? && !step.o_connection.dongle? %>
        <div class="cableimg">
            <%= image_tag(step.i_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "orange")  %>
        </div>
    <% end %>           
<% end %>   <!-- end of step.input_contact.present -->

<% if step.o_connection.cord? && !step.o_connection.dongle? %>
    <div class="cableimg">
        <%= image_tag(step.o_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "green") %>
    </div>      
<% end %>
<div class="productimg">
    <span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-image-width="<%= step.o_connection.image.dimensions.first %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>
    <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
        <%= link_to image_tag(step.o_connection.image.image.url(:medium), class: "oconnection"), "#{step.o_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
        <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
    </div>  
</div>              
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var imgWidth = parseInt($(this).data('imageWidth'));
```

Comment: actually I've had issues with camel case data attributes, try changing that data attribute to imagewidth instead of imageWidth, see if that works.

Comment: Actually for that matter I am not seeing that data attribute in your actual HTML, are you sure that is returning a value at all?

Comment: Tried removing the camel case, and still didn't work. I just added an alert to alert newWidth, and it is the correct value. It seems it's not being passed to the CSS for some reason..